# Working with password field in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Whenever I am trying to insert records it gives me error message for password field as '

> The value 'SomePassword' is not valid for password

**Model**

```
public byte[] Password { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<label class="input">
<i class="icon-append fa fa-tag"></i>
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Class.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtPassword" })
<span asp-validation-for="Class.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</label>
```

When checked in controller the `ModelState` is invalid and error message is coming why is it so ?. I have tried with `DataType.Password` on Password field, but still no success

The Password column has datatype 'Varbinary' in sql server.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Don't use Entity Framework entity types as ViewModels.

Comment: @Dai I didn't get you. Can you please explain it ?

Comment: Create a separate class as a ViewModel for your page (with a `String` password member) then write code that loads/saves it with your EF entity type (such as performing the password hashing).

Comment: I don't know for definite (hence comment not answer) but I would guess this is because the password entered by the user is a string, I doubt the model binder will automatically convert it to a byte array. You need a ViewModel in between which accepts the password as a string, then converts it to a byte array (with any hashing or whatever encryption you are planning to use) before creating the database entity and saving it. As the other commenter said, most design experts now say you should really use ViewModels for your views, and not use the DB entities directly.

Comment: @Dai  Thanks for the help !

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A password is never entered by the user as a byte arrray, it is converted into one before hashing.

The mvc model binder has no built in capability to convert any input to a byte array, and even though you could write a custom model binder I don't see why you would want to, as a plain string is much easier to type.

Even though the SQL type may be varbinary, you do not want the user to enter this representation in your model.

You should set the `Class.Password` property to be a string, and then in your server side code, you should be hashing the password.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);` will convert the string password into a `byte[]` but it on it's own it is not sufficient for secure password storage.

I strongly recommend you take a look at https://www.asp.net/identity if you have the option to upgrade your password requriements.

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

why dont you start with the Password model of the Default Account, and modify it to fit your actual need? or you have a very unusal password requirement which need byte[]? otherwise you should just convert it when you actually needed to...

Model

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote would only work if class `Model` has a property called `Class`, and the property `Class` has a property `Password`.

Try using this instead:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, ...
```

Also, the `Password` property in your ViewModel needs to be a `string`. Both the Web and MVC cannot use `byte[]` for text input controls.

You can **store** a `byte[]` - hashed and encrypted, the best approach! - but it first comes in as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help !